# Redux with react, how to pass and receive the data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I am doing a login form for react and I am using redux for the state management. This will be connected to server but I want to try it first with a some data.

I don't know how to pass data coming from the user input to the reducers. Here is my code for the onsubmit hadler:

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

const LoginHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const userCreds = {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        };
    
        setToken(Math.random().toString());
    
        dispatch(login());
      };
```

and here is my code for the slice:

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state) => {
      state.authenticated = "";
      state.token = "";
      state.currentUser = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
      };
    },

    logout: (state) => {
      state.authenticated = false;
      state.token = null;
      state.currentUser = null;
    },
  },
});
```

Please teach me how to pass the data from that function to my SLice. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're close, if you're following [this example](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#create-a-redux-state-slice) you just need to make sure your exports are in order.
Then adjust your functions to more closely match the example linked above.

Your login function should look like this:

```js
    login: (state, action) => {
      // I'm ignoring these two for now
      // state.authenticated = "";
      // state.token = "";
      state.currentUser = {
        email: action.payload.email,
        password: action.payload.password,
      };
    },
```

and your login function like this:

```js
const LoginHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const userCreds = {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        };
    
        setToken(Math.random().toString());
    
        dispatch(login(userCreds));
      };
```

You need to pass in the action payload when you `dispatch` the action.